# Need some help with a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using PHP's  [RouteMap](http://code.google.com/p/routemap/) and want to clean up the URL.

The URL's come in the form of:

```
http://localhost/subfolder/index.php?controller/method/arg1
```

How would I convert this to:

```
http://localhost/subfolder/controller/method/arg1
```

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it, but I think you will want the following:

```
 RewriteRule ^/subfolder/controller/(method/.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?controller/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your httpd.conf file:

```
#start your engine
RewriteEngine on
#add www. for any url, not what you asked for, but kinda helpful SEO-wise
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com$1
#rewrite stuff
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(controller/method/arg1)/?$ /index.php?$1
```

That should work. I would change the last line, tho:

```
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(controller/method/arg1)/?$ /index.php?p=$1
```

Now, before you restart apache, try to test if the config file is ok.

```
user$ apachectl configtest
```

And that's about it.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])/$ /productinfo.php?prodID=$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])$ /products/$1/
```

Multiple redirects in the same .htaccess file can be applied in sequence, which is what this does